# Python - How to print out name when a number (in-json) has changed using json

Tags: python, json, for-loop, if-statement

I will start off by showing of the json:

```
{
    "name": "LetsTryThis",
    "grades": [{
            "name": "Stack",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Over",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "flow",
            "pass_grade": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "com",
            "pass_grade": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see everyone has a different name and all of them has a pass_grade where 0 is failed and 1 is passed.

***What I want to do*** - is that I want to make a comparing where I have a new json that looks like:

```
{
  'name': 'LetsTryThis',
  'grades': [
    {
      'name': 'Stack',
      'pass_grade': 0
    },
    {
      'name': 'Over',
      'pass_grade': 1
    },
    {
      'name': 'flow',
      'pass_grade': 0
    },
    {
      'name': 'com',
      'pass_grade': 0
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want it to print out the name whenever someone has passed.

A code I have created:

```
    old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
    new_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis', 'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}

   old_list_grades = [i['pass_grade'] for i in old_list['grades']]
```

The issue is that I got stuck where I just print out all the pass_grades and my idea was maybe to change if there is any changes between old_list and new_list but then I realized I wouldn't be able to print out the names in that case.

So my question once again is that how can I be able to print out the name whenever a pass_grade has been changed from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two lists of names where first list contains names from old list who failed and second contains names from new list of those who passed. Then take an intersection of the lists.

```
old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
new_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis', 'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}

old_failed = [ i['name'] for i in old_list['grades'] if i['pass_grade'] == 0] 
new_passed = [ i['name'] for i in new_list['grades'] if i['pass_grade'] == 1] 

change_to_pass = list(set(old_failed) & set(new_passed)) 
print(change_to_pass)
```

***Update:***

The function `getGradeChangeNames()` would return all the names for which grade has changed, either 0->1 or from 1->0. You can call this function in a loop and pass any old and new lists.

```
def getGradeChangeNames(old_list,new_list):
    old_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in old_list["grades"]}
    new_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in new_list["grades"]}
    changed_grades = [old_name for old_name,old_grade in old_grades.items() if old_grade != new_grades[old_name] ]
    return changed_grades


old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
new_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis', 'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}

getGradeChangeNames(old_list,new_list)
```

Comment: Oh Yeah! I realized one other thing. So if I run this on a while True: where new_list can be changed times to times. Is it possible to update the value of new_list as the old_list so whenever the next check is, it shouldn't print out the pass_grade 1 once again but print whenever it changes back to 0?

Comment: Thats a new requirement, different from your original question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh im sorry! Thanks again for being a saviour! I didnt quite understand what you meant with "function in a loop and pass any old and new lists". Doesn't we need to update the value of old_list whenever there is a change in new_list? so it doesn't repeat it over and over?

Comment: When u call getGradeChangeNames() first time, say u passed list1 and list2 where list1=old list and list2=new list.  When u can the function second time,  you will call with list2=old list and list3=new list. i.e. your new list becomes old list in subsequent calls. But its upto how you mange the running old and new list.

Comment: Ohhhhh alright! I mean it does work like you say thought! It just that I thought it didn't do that at all and was worried about it and I assume if I just want to do 0->1 and not care about 1->0 but to still update the list, What way do I need to continue with that from your loop?

Comment: I don't know enough abt your application to add further. How do u get the new_list eveytime in a loop?

Comment: Oh etc like through a saved json file from computer. Where u open every time in loop. So meaning you can change the file whenever the grade gets passed or not.

Comment: You should update your question with code using whatever you learned from the answers so far including your while loop logic to read from file and point out which part your are having issues with. Or may be post another question.

Comment: Yeah I think so too! i will do that! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a dict of name and grade and then do the checking.

**Ex:**

```
old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
new_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis', 'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}

old_list_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in old_list["grades"]}
new_list_grades = {i["name"]: i["pass_grade"] for i in new_list["grades"]}

for k, v in old_list_grades.items():
    if v == 0:
        if new_list_grades.get(k) == 1:
            print(k, v)
```

**Output:**

```
Over 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it supposed to say Over 1?

Comment: `print(k, new_list_grades.get(k))`

Comment: Oh Yeah! I realized one other thing. So if I run this on a while True: where new_list can be changed times to times. Is it possible to update the value of new_list as the old_list so whenever the next check is, it shouldn't print out the pass_grade 1 once again but print whenever it changes back to 0?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little verbose as I am not that familiar with python

```
old_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis',  'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0},{'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
new_list = {'name': 'LetsTryThis', 'grades': [{'name': 'Stack', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Over', 'pass_grade': 1}, {'name': 'Flow', 'pass_grade': 0}, {'name': 'Com', 'pass_grade': 0}]}
fails = [name['name'] for name in old_list['grades'] if name['pass_grade'] == 0]
now_passes = [name['name'] for name in new_list['grades'] if name['pass_grade'] == 1 and name['name'] in fails ]
print(now_passes)
```